# Общая установка grunt и зависимостей для нескольких проектов

Tags: npm, grunt

Есть N проектов с идентичной конфигурацией. Все они находятся в соседних директориях. Я хочу в каждый проект добавить конфигурацию grunt: `Gruntfile.js` и `package.json`.

При установке через `npm install` в каждом проекте появляется `node_modules`.

```
.
├── project1
│    └── node_modules
├── project2
│    └── node_modules
│   ...
└── projectN
     └── node_modules
```

Это выглядит избыточно: было бы достаточно одной общей, либо вообще глобальной установки.

Пробовал установить все зависимости глобально:

```
npm install -g
```

Но в проектах, где уже есть `Gruntfile.js` и `package.json`, но нет `node_modules` со всеми зависимостями, получаю такой результат:

```
$ grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

> **Вопрос:** как запустить grunt без локальной установки всех модулей? Подойдет как вариант с глобальной установкой, так и общая `node_modules` только для этих проектов.

---

Все `Gruntfile.js` идентичны, отличаются только названия проектов и открываемые порты на localhost. Всё `package.json` полностью идентичны и всегда будут идентичны для этой группы проектов.

И я конечно же читал документацию по ссылке. Там как раз указывается на "Install project dependencies with npm install.", но нет способа использовать глобально установленные зависимости.

Можно было бы сделать символические ссылки в каждой директории, но это какой-то костыль, я его буду использовать только если нет способа «из коробки».

Comment: грант вроде написал, что надо грант локально иметь в проекте. поставь все глобально и только грант локально, может получиться запустить

Comment: @greybutton попробовал `npm install grunt-cli; grunt`, получаю тот же результат. Вообще после опыта использования make, rake и invoke для меня очень странным кажется опыт использования grunt. Весь смысл таких инструментов для автоматизации задач в том, что они сразу работают из любой папки, где лежит конфиг.

Comment: это не проблема grunt - это особенность npm. раньше внутри каждого модуля в node_modules был свой node_modules в котором лежали зависимости для этого модуля.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman чувствую себя Винни-Пухом, залезшим в лужу. Что, никак нельзя обойтись без этого легиона `node_modules`?

Comment: вроде в новой версии они научились жить без этого, но я не уверен. npm изначально был простым шелл скриптом который все копировал в директорию проекта.

Comment: grunt-cli должен быть глобальным, а локальным просто grunt. Если я правильно понял ты grunt-cli локально ставил, а я имел в виду `npm install -g grunt-cli`, `npm install grunt --save-dev`, `grunt`